# Using v-model with nested components in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my admin app I have an , inside this component I also have Vue 2's quill rich editor which uses v-model for its data, now I want to pass the v-model from my child vue-2-editor to my own parent component, the docs say you can have custom v-model in yur compoennt with props value and emiting an 'input' event with that value, but how can I pass one v-model to another, from child to parent component.

Im using vue 2 editor, A text editor using Vue.js and Quill:
https://github.com/davidroyer/vue2-editor

My component :

```
<template>
<div style="width:auto; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction.column;">
    <button @click="editorVisible = true">Show Editor</button>
    <vue-editor v-model="value" :editorToolbar="customToolbar" useCustomImageHandler @imageAdded="handleImageAdded"></vue-editor>
</div>
</template>
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script>
import { VueEditor } from 'vue2-editor';
export default {
name: 'ADMINeditor',


props:
{
    value:{ required:true, type:String }
},


data()
{
    return { 
        editorVisible:false
    }
},


methods:
{

    wrote()
    {
        this.$emit('input', this.value);
    }
}


}
</script>
<!--STYLES-->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

I want to be able to do:

```
<admin-editor v-model="text"></admin-editor>
```

More info about -model in custom components.

https://alligator.io/vuejs/add-v-model-support/

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR**

```
<vue-editor :value="value" @input="$emit('input' $event)" />
```

---

Like you said, to support `v-model` in a component you need to add a model prop and emit a model event to let the parent know you want to update data.

By default `v-model` uses a `value` prop and an `input` event, but, since 2.2.0+, you can [customize the component `v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model).

The `<vue-editor>` component uses `v-model` default property and event, so it expects a `value` property and emits an `input` event whenever the data is updated.

So:

`<vue-editor v-model="value" />`

Is equivalent to:

`<vue-editor :value="xxx" @input="onXxxUpdate"`

---

Your `<admin-editor>` component also needs to support `v-model`, so you need to do the same `<vue-editor>` component does, add a model property and emit a model event.

Then, emit an `input` event from `<admin-editor>` whenever the `<vue-editor>` component emits an `input` event.

```
<template>
  <vue-editor :value="value" @input="onEditorUpdate" />
</template>

<script>
import { VueEditor } from 'vue2-editor'

export default {
  name: 'AdminEditor',

  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },

  methods: {
    onEditorUpdate(newVal) {
      //           ^^^^^^
      //           <vue-editor> input event payload
      this.$emit('input', newVal)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by creating separate private variable (in `data()`, not a prop), and use it as the `v-model` on the `vue-editor` components, Than watch it and emit `@input` event on change, Also to receive update from the parent v-model, you need to watch the `value` prop and update the private variable.

```
<template>
    <div style="width:auto; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction.column;">
        <button @click="editorVisible = true">Show Editor</button>
        <vue-editor v-model="pvalue" :editorToolbar="customToolbar" useCustomImageHandler
            @imageAdded="handleImageAdded"></vue-editor>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { VueEditor } from 'vue2-editor'
export default {
    props: {
        value: { required: true, type: String }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            pvalue: '',
        }
    },
    watch: {
        value(val) {
            this.pvalue = val
        },
        pvalue(val) {
            this.$emit('input', val)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Note `v-model="pvalue"`