# Modifying variable in method does not update child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I'm struggling with how Vue updates props/child components.

Suppose the following component:

```js
<template>
  <v-card>
    <Modification v-model="newObject"></Modification>
    <OtherComponent @close="resetObject"></OtherComponent>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
import { MyClass } from "classes";
import Modification from "b";
import OtherComponent from "a";

export default {
  name: "MyForm",
  components: { OtherComponent, Modification },
  props: {
    existingObject: {
      type: [MyClass, typeof undefined],
      required: false,
      default: undefined
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      newObject: undefined
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.newObject =
      this.existingObject !== undefined
        ? this.existingObject.clone()
        : new MyClass();
  },
  methods: {
    resetObject() {
      this.newObject =
        this.existingObject !== undefined
          ? this.existingObject.clone()
          : new MyClass();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

How MyClass is defined:

```js
export class MyClass {
  constructor({ a= null, b=null} = {}) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
  toPayload(){
    return { a:this.a , b:this.b };
  }
  clone() {
    return new MyClass(this.toPayload());
  }
}
```

This component receives an existing class instance of `MyClass`, clones it (clone => new MyClass(...)) and passes it to the `Modification` component which does some modification upon user input. So far so good, the modification works. However once the `customEvent` is fired and the `resetObject` method is called the `newObject` is reset but the `Modification` component is not updated with the now reset `newObject` - it still displays the old, modified values. I also checked inside the `Modification` component wether or not the update happens: It doesn't.

Why is this the case? Am I missing a step? Am I not aware of a Vue specific mechanism?

Note: I found this [blog](https://medium.com/emblatech/ways-to-force-vue-to-re-render-a-component-df866fbacf47) which provides solutions to force the `Modification`component to update. For now it seems to hacky for me to be "THE" solution.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Adding a computed property which includes a `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.newObject))` fires everytime `newObject` is updated.
Also adding a `<span> {{ newObject.a }} </span>` to the template updates evertime.

Both these tests convince me that the variable not only should be but actually IS reactive.

EDIT 2:

The `Modification` component consists, for now, of 2 Input components.
It looks like this.

```js
<template>
  <v-card-text>
    <ModifyA v-model="object.a" @input="handleInput" />
    <ModifyB v-model="object.b" @input="handleInput" />
  </v-card-text>
</template>
<script>
import { MyClass } from "classes";
import ModifyA from "...";
import ModifyB from "...";
export default {
  name: "ShiftFormFields",
  components: { ModifyA, ModifyB },
  props: {
    value: {
      type: MyClass,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return { object: this.value };
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput() {
      this.$emit("input", this.object);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

If I try adding the `ModifyA` Input into the component instead of the `Modification` component like this

```js
<template>
  <v-card>
    <ModifyA v-model="newObject.a"></Modification>
    <OtherComponent @close="resetObject"></OtherComponent>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

the `resetObject` also resets the value shown in the `ModifyA` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58886233/8226216) answer.

As I edited my original post with the definition of the `Modification` component

```js
<template>
  <v-card-text>
    <ModifyA v-model="object.a" @input="handleInput" />
    <ModifyB v-model="object.b" @input="handleInput" />
  </v-card-text>
</template>
<script>
import ModifyA from "...";
import ModifyB from "...";
export default {
  name: "ShiftFormFields",
  components: { ModifyA, ModifyB },
  props: {
    value: {
      type: MyClass,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return { object: this.value };
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput() {
      this.$emit("input", this.object);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

it shows the "problem" why the Fields `ModifyA` and `ModifyB` do not update if the `value` updates in the parent component.

As seen in the above definition the variable `object` is only set to the `value` once the Component is initialized. It follows that `object` is not reactive on behalf of `value`.

To solve this one can use the approach of the above mentioned answer:

```js
<template>
  <v-card-text>
    <ModifyA v-model="object.a" />
    <ModifyB v-model="object.b" />
  </v-card-text>
</template>
<script>
import { Shift } from "classes";
import ModifyA from "...";
import ModifyB from "...";
export default {
  name: "ShiftFormFields",
  components: { ModifyA, ModifyB },
  props: {
    value: {
      type: MyClass,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return { object: this.value };
  },
  watch: {
    value(val) {
      this.object = val;
    },
    object(value) {
      this.$emit("input", value);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Due to the watcher, the `object` variable is updated whenever the `value` get's updated by the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show how `MyClass` clones your object.

I'm guessing something in there isn't reactive.

You can check by doing `console.log()` and see what it says on the console.

If it's reactive, it should show something like `MyClass {__ob__: Observer}`

You can probably use `this.$set('propName', value)` to fix your problem

Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set

> Adds a property to a reactive object, ensuring the new property is also reactive, so triggers view updates. This must be used to add new properties to reactive objects, as Vue cannot detect normal property additions (e.g. this.myObject.newProperty = 'hi').

Comment: Indeed `console.log(newObject)` shows `Object { __ob__ : Object }` but all fields are replaced by getters and setters so i suppose it is reactive. Please also have a look at the two "tests" i added in an edit of my post.

Comment: Furthermore using `this.$set(this, "newObject", ...)` does not work. The Values shown inside the `Modification` component remain the "old edited" ones.

Answer (score 0):

Either there is a typo in your post, or the typo also exists in your code and is the source of your problem.

In your post you're binding "newObjekt" to the Modification component, but your parent component has the property "newObject"

is this the source of your issue?

Comment: Sorry, this is just a typo in my Post. Checked it and edited my post.